# fill select input value dirrectly without java script

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

is it possible fill model's field by value of select input ?
without using java script cod.
in tbl_purchase , i have Idtbl_bank . how can i fill in view directly?

```
@model Project.Models.tbl_purchase

  <select id="Idtbl_bank" class="span5">
  <option>---select bank name ---</option>

    @foreach (var item in ViewBag.BankNames as List<Project.Models.tbl_bank>)
    {                      
        <option  value="@item.id">@item.namebank </option>
    }
  </select>
```

Comment: This code isn't using javascript, the @foreach executes on the server.

Comment: what do you mean ? i said i have a field(idtbl_bank) in Project.Models.tbl_purchase that i wanna fill it by select input value

Comment: should i put id of select input to my model's name ? just this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `Idtbl_bank` is the model field in which you want to store the selected value (and also assuming that `tbl_bank.id` and `Idtbl_bank` are compatible types):

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Idtbl_bank, ViewBag.BankNames, "id", "namebank")
```

If you look at what this renders, you'll see that the key is the `name` attribute of the `select` element:

```
  <select id="Idtbl_bank" name="Idtbl_bank" class="span5">
```

The `name` determines what the form field is submitted as, not the `id` attribute.

Comment: @niki There should be a tick at the side of the answer - if you click on that tick it will turn green, marking the answer as accepted.